How to rename a solidworks features from its properties?
I'm making VBAs to clean the feature tree and automate some process in the way to lighten the work on big welded structures.
Every weldment and sheetmetal features in my cutListFolder have a property called 'DESIGNATION', and I'd like to change the feature name to be the same String as its designation.
But right now, I can't get it to work on all of the features. Some of them got renamed just right, but others got renamed with the designation of another feature, or didn't get renamed at all.
Using  Debug.Print, and running the code multiple times, I can see that the I manage to retrieve the designation, but the swFeat.Name = design line don't seems to take effect
Does any one have an idea on what might be wrong?
Const PRP_DESIGN As String = "DESIGNATION"

Dim swApp As Object
Sub main()
    
try_:
    
    On Error GoTo catch_

    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Dim swModelExt As SldWorks.ModelDocExtension
    Set swModelExt = swModel.Extension
    Dim customPropManager As SldWorks.CustomPropertyManager
    
    If Not swModel Is Nothing Then
        If swModel.GetType() = swDocumentTypes_e.swDocPART Then
            Debug.Print "Start Macro Renaming"
            Debug.Print ""

            Dim vCutLists As Variant
            vCutLists = GetCutLists(swModel)
            
            If UBound(vCutLists) <> -1 Then
                Dim swFeat As SldWorks.Feature
                Dim i As Integer
                For i = 0 To UBound(vCutLists)
                    Set swFeat = vCutLists(i)
                    Set customPropManager = swFeat.CustomPropertyManager
                    Dim design As String
                    Dim wasResolved As Boolean
                    customPropManager.Get5 PRP_DESIGN, True, "", design, wasResolved
                    
                    If Not wasResolved Or design = "" Then
                        design = "Designation unavailable"
                    End If
                    Debug.Print "   Renaming " & swFeat.Name & " in " & design
                    swFeat.Name = design
                Next
            End If
            Debug.Print "Pièces renommées"
            Debug.Print ""

            Debug.Print "End of Macro Renaming"
            Debug.Print ""
            Debug.Print ""
        Else
            Err.Raise vbError, "", "Only part document is supported"
        End If
    Else
        Err.Raise vbError, "", "Open part document"
    End If
    
    GoTo finally_
    
catch_:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
finally_:
    
End Sub


Are all the designations unique? Because 2 features can not have the same name. You need to add an increment number. Same goes for the default name "Designation unavailable"

Yes, every designation is unique (they are made by another macro that does use an increment number). Though You're right for the default name, it's not the meat of the problem here, but I'll fix it to be different for any unresolved feature. Thank you

Expanding on my comment:
a sketch, folder, cut list item etc... are all features, so if any of those have the same name as the the target name (even if they are of a different type) it won't rename. You can check by trying to manually rename it.
if that work you can try to first select the feature before renaming,                     by replacing: 'swFeat.Name = design', with:
swModel.ClearSelection2 True
swModel.Extension.SelectByID2 swFeat.Name, "SUBWELDFOLDER", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0
' or: swFeat.Select2 False, -1
If swModel.SelectionManager.GetSelectedObject6(1, -1) Is Nothing Then
     Debug.Print "Can not select feature"
Else
     swModel.SelectionManager.GetSelectedObject6(1, -1).Name = design
End If

or send me a test file where that doesn't work, and I'll look into it
